# -[UITableViewCellAccessibility _accessibilityReuseChildren:forMockParent:] crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, accessibility, voiceover

On fabric.io/crashlytics, we got a lot of UITableView related accessibility crashes. Ive seen it happen when VoiceOver is active.

It also looks like it is only related to iOS 8.1.2 and 8.2. We have not seen any other iOS versions crash on it.

Is anybody else experiencing this issue, or can anybody help?

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000196097bd0 objc_msgSend + 16
1  UIKit                          0x000000018352b7dc -[UITableViewCellAccessibility _accessibilityReuseChildren:forMockParent:] + 496
2  UIKit                          0x000000018353c070 -[UITableViewCellAccessibilityElement tableViewCell] + 260
3  UIKit                          0x000000018353ca90 -[UITableViewCellAccessibilityElement isAccessibilityElement] + 24
4  UIAccessibility                0x0000000192723e4c _appendChildrenToArrayStartingAtIndexWithChildren + 352
5  UIAccessibility                0x0000000192723b20 _addAXElementsToArrayFromObject + 1620
6  UIAccessibility                0x000000019272349c _appendVendedAXElementsFromUIElements + 288
7  UIAccessibility                0x0000000192723358 _createAXUIElementsFromUIElements + 160
8  UIAccessibility                0x00000001927221e8 _copyParameterizedAttributeValueCallback + 208
9  AXRuntime                      0x000000018aa684c0 _AXXMIGCopyParameterizedAttributeValue + 256
10 AXRuntime                      0x000000018aa64248 _XCopyParameterizedAttributeValue + 412
11 AXRuntime                      0x000000018aa6f650 mshMIGPerform + 272
12 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001850b2548 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
13 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001850b24a8 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 436
14 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001850b0428 __CFRunLoopRun + 1640
15 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000184fdd1f4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
16 GraphicsServices               0x000000018e4076fc GSEventRunModal + 168
17 UIKit                          0x000000018996e10c UIApplicationMain + 1488
18 deredactie                     0x0000000100075400 main (main.m:14)
19 libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000196702a08 start + 4
```

Comment: This looks like an Apple issue, which may have been fixed in 8.3. Please open a bug report with Apple and post the radar number here so people can clone it.

Comment: Are you using Auto Release Pool thing?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for fixing this crash which help me below

In fill item method

```
self.contentView.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
self.contentView.accessibilityLabel = @"some text";
```

As I've found crash can be reproduced on iOS up 8.0 to 8.2.